# Process can't access file in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using visual studio 2017 for writing my C++ program. In my recent program, I am reading parameters from a text file created by notepad. My program works fine as expected , if I don't show text file in solution explorer. But when I open it by double clicking the file in solution explorer, modify parameter values  and try to run my program, it opens a save dialogue box and when I hit save button it does not let me save and produces error something like "The process can't access the file, it is being used by another program". I checked everything thing, but none of my program is using this file.

I need help to figure out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are opening this file in Visual Studio and also your program? That sounds like two programs trying to access the same resource. Try removing it from VS, use a text editor to modify it, then close it and run your program.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, maybe remove that tag and add others more appropriate to avoid further backslash.

Comment: Thanks MikeS159. My program works, if I use text editor other than VS. I am wondering, is it possible to include text file in solution explorer, modify in VS and then use it in the same program.If it is not possible then why a text file template is provided in VS?